# CSS fill parent available space

Tags: html, css

I know that question asked a lot of times, but I didn't found solution to my problem.

I have this html code:

```
<html style="height: 100%">
    <body style="height: 100%">
        <div style="height: 100%">
            <div>Title</div>
            <div style="height: 100%">Content</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want that my DIV with the content will fill the rest space in the parent div.
Every question that I saw before said to do `style="height: 100%"` in the child DIV.
With `style="height: 100%"` it gets the **same size** of the parent div, so my page became larger then 100% (the page have scrollbar).

[image: height: 100%]

(The html, body and parent div tags are same as the viewport)

I just want to fill the parent div with the available free space, not more than that.

[image: fill available space]

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JD5N8/) you can find live example.

Can I do it?

Comment: How old of browsers are you looking to support?

Comment: Sure, http://jsfiddle.net/JD5N8/. As you can see I added the borders, like in my images.

Comment: I mean are you wanting to support IE8 up or something?

Comment: IE9 and above, Chrome, FF.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: In that case you can use the linked question above. If you were looking to support IE10+, you could likely use flexbox (a better option)

Comment: If the content in the `content div` is too large (would overflow), which element should scroll (if any)?

Comment: I prefer the hole page, not just the content

Comment: This can't be everything: you could add a background to the body, move it horizontally down by `title div` height, give `title div` background and there you go (if your questions is only about styling). Is there also a footer? Will there be effects, something that relies on an independant element within the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to make `title` 100% height.....there is no point of it.....general idea is to have a `container` with `100%` height and in that you create your child class divs

- make title `20%` and content `80%` - *preferably, best option*
   
   [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zr3TQ/)
- or use `overflow:hidden` on `content` - *only if you know for sure that content is not in excess to be hidden, this option is only to hide the excess of div when content is not there*
- or use `calc()` in css ([cross browser but not  supported by old browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc))
   [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zr3TQ/1/)

Comment: I don't know the title size. It can be bigger or include images, so I cant set it size. also the content can be very long, so the overflow is important. The min height of the content should fill the parent.

Comment: `overflow:hidden` is not a solution, it just ignores the situation

Comment: `calc` is cross browser, just not in old browsers

Comment: I dont want to make the title 100% height. Just that the content will fill the rest of the space.

Comment: @ZachSaucier : yeah...i meant the same...but english beats me...and please allow and wait for edits in first 10mins.....updated! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor What can I do if I don't know what is the height of the title?

Comment: @nrofis : consider `calc` if you want to *fix* the title..its a handy tool in CSS!! :)

Comment: @nrofis : whats gonna be the content in `title` part?? 1 image and 1 line text or would it be dynamic?

Comment: it would be Dynamic. The font is large, and I cant know how many lines will be in it. Images can be also in the title

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56459/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-nrofis).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without Javascript at all.

Assuming:

- there are no other sections/elements (required)
- the title might be fix-height (I assume this cheekily)

Position the title `div` and the content `div` both absolute and wrap the content within another `div` that's allowed to overflow. The content `div` will be positioned from top and from bottom.

**HTML Structure:**

```
<div class="title">
    Title
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-content">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.title {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/43zF2/

Answer (score 0):

It seems it not possible through only css. You can use jquery.

Try this demo. With this, you can manage the responsive layout also

[http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/7WC7N/25/](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24466755/edit)

**EDIT**

**http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/7WC7N/27/**

```
var _init = function () {
    parentHeight = $('.parent').outerHeight(true);
    titleHeight = $('.title').outerHeight(true);
    childHeight = parentHeight - titleHeight;
    $('.child').height(childHeight);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    _init();
})
$(window).resize(function () {
    _init();
});
```

Comment: Yes thats true. I have made some changes in code Try this link `http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/7WC7N/27/`. I have used `outerHeight(true)` instead of `outerHeight()` and it works with the margin also.

Answer (score 0):

Another Javascript-less solution, that is more *flex* ible is using Flexbox.

In contrast to my other answer this also allows flexible title height too.

**HTML Structure:**

```
<div class="title">
    Title
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-content">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
}
```

The `body` is in flex-column mode. The content has a `flex` value of `1` to fill the `body`. The `content-content` wrapper is allowed to overflow.

This works in Firefox 28+ and Chrome 33+ and should work in IE 11+ (can't test it ATM). IE 10 probably needs some quirky (CSS) workarounds/additions and vendor-prefixes of course.

[You can use flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

See this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J63vF/1/